# xamarin forms circle image plug in doesn't work

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am trying to use the plug in from here https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin

I have installed but when I try to add ImageCircleRenderer.Init(); it says that it doesn't exist in the current context.

Can you help please?

Comment: Did you add the ImageCirclePlugin package to the android/ios/windows project besides your PLC?

Comment: Yes I forgot to add the plug in for each individual platforms... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I forgot to add the plug in packages for each platform.

Thanks Thom for the tip :)